# type inconsistency between std::setw() and ostream::width()

Tags: c++, iostream, iomanip

This simple code

```
template<typename T>
std::ostream&operator<<(std::ostream&s, some_array_type<T> const&x)
{
  auto w = s.width();
  auto p = s.precision();
  s << x[0];
  for(std::size_t i=1; i!=x.size(); ++i)
    s << ' ' << std::setw(w) << std::setprecision(p) << m[i];
  return s;
}
```

intends to print a `some_array_type` with the width and precision for each element equal to the current values, allowing code like

```
some_array_type<double> x;
std::cout << std::setw(12) << std::setprecision(8) << x << std::endl;
```

However, as clang points out, the type returned by `ostream::width()` and `ostream::precision()` (`std::size_t`) differs from the argument type accepted by the manipulators `std::setw` and `std::setprecision` (`int`), such that above code triggers two warnings.

Is there a particular reason for this inconsistency or is this simply a minor flaw in the C++ standard (or an error of the libc++ implementation)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it's clearly an error in the implementation.  The standard says
that `std::ios_base::width` and `std::ios_base::precision` use
`std::streamsize`, which is required to be a “signed basic
integral type”—on a modern system, I would expect `long long`, or possibly `long`.  `std::size_t` is required to be unsigned,
and is arguably not a "basic integral type" either (although it might be
a typedef for one).

The fact remains that the member functions `std::ios_base::width` and
`std::ios_base::precision` may (and probably do) use a different type
than the manipulators (which are always `int`).  And if
`std::streamsize` is `long long`, there will be values of it which don't
fit into an `int`.  The probability of such a value actually occuring in
correct code seems small enouogh to me that I would just stick with
`int` (and not obfuscate with `auto`), and not worry about the risk of
overflow.  Alternatively, I'd use `int`, but with an `assert` before, to
ensure than there was no overflow.

Finally: normally, the width is the total width of the element.  So the
width you should be setting is `w / x.size() - 1` (including for the
first element).  At least in theory; I'm not sure how useful that is for
array types (and I certainly wouldn't insist on it, as long as the
modified semantics are well documented).  And of course, precision is
sticky; you don't have to set it for each value.  (On the other hand,
the user should remember and restore it.)